# Herkunft der Nachsilbe "-wesen"

Tags: etymology

Die Nachsilbe "-wesen" wird in für eine Reihe (mehr oder weniger bekannter) formaler, abstrakter "Branchenbezeichnungen" verwendet.

> Bauwesen, Brauwesen, Bankenwesen, Molkereiwesen, …

Ich verstehe, was diese Wörter bedeuten, doch es fällt mir schwer, es zu umschreiben, und vor allem sehe ich keinen wirklichen Zusammenhang mit dem Substantiv "Wesen".

Bei DWDS ist gar nichts zu finden.
Nun frage ich mich, ob "-wesen" wirklich mit "das Wesen" verwandt ist, oder vielleicht von "wissen" kommt.

- Hat jemand eine belegbare Etymologie vom Suffix "-wesen" im Sinne oben genannter Beispiele (bitte nicht auf "Unwesen" eingehen)?
- Wie passt die Verwendung mit den Bedeutungen von "das Wesen" (damalig, heutig) zusammen?

Comment: Interessante Frage! Da ich keine Belege habe hier ein Kommentar: "Wesen" als Entität die aus einer Menge an Personen mit einer Gemeinsamkeit entsteht. "Gemeinwesen" kommt der Sache doch schon sehr nahe als das "Wesen" das allen gemein ist, während Bauwesen nur diejenigen umfasst, die im Bau tätig sind.

Comment: Canoo.net leitet das Wort her, indem sie von einem [fiktiven Wort "wesen"](http://canoo.net/wordformation/wesen:V:haben) ausgehen, dann das Nomen "Wesen" von dem Verb ableiten und dies an zum Beispiel "Bau" anhängen. Ironischerweise hat der Duden einen Eintrag für das Verb "wesen" (gehoben, veraltet). Der Herkunft von dem Verb "wesen" lässt aber keine Rückschlüsse auf das Suffix "-wesen" ziehen. Zumindest entgeht es mir. – Ganz nebenbei gibt es viele Wörter mit "wesen" (z.b. wesentlich), wo mir der Zusammenhang mit dem Nomen "Wesen" nicht offensichtlich ist.

Comment: @Em1... interessantes Tool. Kann aber irreführend sein. "wesen" gab es tatsächlich. Da kommt "war" und "gewesen" her. "Verwesen" allerdings gehört da nicht so einfach mit rein. Zumindest laut DWDS hat es einen anderen Ursprung und wurde unter dem Einfluss von "ver+wesen" ein wenig verändert. Landverweser wiederum ist "wesen" pur.

Comment: Liest du einen anderen DWB-Artikel als ich? In meinem werden gleich am Anfang die unterschiedlichen Bedeutungsgruppen von _Wesen_ diskutiert, darunter auch die für _-wesen_ relevante: „in vielgestaltiger anwendung bei ganz unscharfer begrifflicher fassung tritt _wesen_ als allgemeine gegenstandsbezeichnung auf (I J). es bezieht sich namentlich auf komplexe objekte (z. b. stoffgebiete der geistigen beschäftigung, doch auch auf dingliches, 'zeug, kram') … sprachgeschichtlich bedeutsam wird dieser gebrauch als basis des kompositionentyps _schulwesen_, _finanzwesen_ etc. (s. I J 7).“

Comment: Und mehr dann eben im Abschnitt I J 7.

Comment: @chirlu... oh, das habe ich nicht gesehen. Ich hatte bei J vor allem wegen "komplex" gedacht: "AHA, hier ist es, aber dann nach den ersten Unterpunkten habe ich weitergescrollt. Hätte nicht gedacht, dass das so nebenbei kurz nach allerleid Redewendungen erwähnt wird.

Comment: @chirlu... I think I'll just take out the DWB-bit and say that DWDS said nothing. Then someone can sculpt an answer because I think the DBW-article is a bit heavy.

Comment: Emanuel wird hiermit beauftragt, den DWB-Artikel zu einer Antwort zusammenzufassen ;)

Comment: Vielleicht ist mein Verständnis naiv, aber Ist "wesen" nicht einfach eine [Variante](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urindogermanische_Kopula#Die_resultierenden_Formen) vom "sein"? Das erklärt sowohl den Suffix wie das Substantiv.

Comment: @dirkt... nein, ist es nicht. "wesan" war ein von "sein" unabhängiges Verb und ist erst mit der Zeit assimiliert worden. Ausserdem sehe ich keinen zwingenden Zusammenhang zwischen dem Sinn "sein" und den Wörtern in der Frage.

Comment: @Emanuel: Das meinte ich mit "Variante". Das Substantiv "Wesen" beschreibt, wie ein Ding ist, was es "ausmacht", also die "Essenz" (wieder eine Variante von "sein"). Der Suffix -wesen beschreibt das Wort davor als Kategorie, also wieder "wie es ist", "was es ausmacht". Wie gesagt, vielleicht ist es naiv, aber für mich ergibt es Sinn.

Comment: Kommt schon Leute: ich bin ziemlich neugierig geworden. Weiß wirklich keiner eine Antwort? Falls doch, könnte der oder diejenigen bitte vielleicht eine Antwort schreiben? Ich bin wirklich neugierig geworden ;-)

Comment: @dirkt... ja, jetzt versteh ich, was du meinst. Ja macht Sinn. Mach doch ne Antwort draus. Die Etymologie ist bei DWB erwähnt (siehe Chirlu's Kommentar)

Comment: @Emanuel: Es ist nur meine persönliche Interpretation, und nicht durch irgendetwas belegt. Deshalb lasse ich es lieber als Kommentar.

Comment: @Emanuel *...ndverweser wiederum ist "wesen" pur.*  http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-die-reinste-puromanie-a-295994.html

Comment: Könnte Bauwesen nicht ein zusammengesetztes Nomen sein aus Bau und dem Nomen Wesen? Ein Wesen ist ein lebendiges Gebilde, und im abstrakten Sinne bildet alles, was mit dem Bau zusammengehört, ein solches Wesen. Dann wäre -wesen nicht als Nachsilbe zu verstehen.

Comment: @RalphM.Rickenbach... auch an dich, mach 'ne Antwort draus. Das ist eine mögliche Erklärung für den Zusammenhang und danach habe ich gefragt.

Comment: @idmean... was Sick schreibt könnte scheißegaler mir nicht sein. Ein Mann, der ganze Bücher damit füllt, sich über anderer Leute Schreibfehler lustig zu machen, nein Danke. Die Quintessenz des spießigen, deutschen Kleinbürgers, der alles besser weiß, und doch, jawohl, auch mal lachen kann.... aber natürlich nicht zu viel! Gegen "Röslein rot" hat er bestimmt auch nix.

Comment: @Emanuel Tja, Gesellschaftskritik hat schon immer den Nerv getroffen. Ob Sick nun ein Besserwisser ist, sei dahin gestellt, Fakt ist: Pur wird wie jedes deutsche Adjektiv vor das Nomen gestellt und gebeugt. Aber das mit "Röslein rot" ist ein interessanter Punkt, wenn auch aus einem lyrischen Text.

Comment: @idmean.. ich habe alle seine Bücher gelesen und das als Gesellschaftskritik zu bezeichnen ist wohl ein bisschen weit hergeholt. ZUm Thema bitte das hier ab Seite 11 lesen http://www.ds.uzh.ch/_files/uploads/studarb/24.pdf   Es ist leider nicht immer so einfach wie Sick es mit seiner Mittelschulgrammatik darstellt.

Comment: @idmean... zum Thema "pur" im speziellen Seit 28 ff

Comment: @Emanuel Der Artikel zielt meiner Ansicht nach darauf ab, dass die Allgemeinheit sich Phrasen aus der Werbung aneignet. D.h. Gesellschaftskritik. (Kann aber auch sein, dass ich Sick überschätze und es ihm nicht wirklich um das geht.) Der verlinkte Text sieht interessant aus, werde ich bei Gelegenheit lesen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das Deutsche erlaubt zusammengesetzte Nomen. Wie @dirkt in einem Kommentar geschrieben hat, beschreibt das Nomen Wesen die Essenz von Etwas.

Gemäss [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wesen) ist ein Wesen

1. in bestimmter Art und Weise in Erscheinung Tretendes, meist lebendiger Organismus
2. ohne Plural: alle Charaktereigenschaften, die sich im Verhalten und Denken eines Menschen widerspiegeln
3. das Charakteristische an etwas, das seine Eigenart ausmacht
4. Treiben, Tumult, Aufstand

Somit wäre das Bau-Wesen alles, was den Bau charakterisiert. Anders ausgedrückt, alles, was *dem Wesen nach* zum Bau gehört.

In diesem Sinne ist *-wesen* nicht als Nachsilbe zu verstehen.

So werden in der gleichen Quelle als Unterbegiffe folgende genannt:

Für Definition 1: Geisterwesen, Hexenwesen

Für Definition 3: Bankwesen, Postwesen, Rechtswesen

Für Definition 4: Unwesen

Die gleiche Quelle definiert -wesen auch als gebundenes Lexem, abgeleitet vom Nomen, mit der Bedeutung: gesamter Bereich von etwas; alles, was zu einem bestimmten Bereich gehört.

Gebundene Lexeme sind Wortbestandteile, die nicht für sich alleine stehen, aber anders als Affixe keine grammatische, sondern eine semantische Bedeutung tragen.

Die Herkunft geht, wie verschiedentlich erwähnt, auf *wesan* zurück, welches im Wesentlichen *sein, existieren* bedeutet.

Answer (score 4):

Die Frage ist schon etwas älter, aber ich hab den Eindruck, dass die bisherigen Antworten den Punkt noch nicht ganz treffen. Insbesondere halt ich die akzeptierte Antwort für falsch. In den zitierten Komposita steht *-wesen* meiner Auffasung nach **nicht** für "die Essenz", für "das Wesentliche".

Die Etymologie von *Wesen* wird ja bei [Pfeifer](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Wesen) hinlänglich beschrieben, auch die Zusammenhänge zu *gewesen*, "[verwesen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verwesen)", und "Verweser" werden deutlich. Der semantische Kern von "Wesen" ist *sein*. Das "Wesentliche" bezeichnet die *spezifische Seinsweise*, also *die Essenz*, *das Grundlegende*, *die Eigenart*.

Für die Bedeutung von *-wesen* in Komposita ist aber eine andere, ebenfalls bei Pfeifer und im dwds erwähnte Bedeutungsebene verantwortlich: "-wesen" auf geht die Bedeutung *Tun und Treiben* zurück, dem auch "Unwesen" zugrundeliegt (vgl. "sein Unwesen treiben") - der Präfix "Un-" bedeutet hier nicht logische Negation, sondern drückt eine wertende Negation, Unwerturteil aus (wie etwa auch bei "Unzeit"); vgl. auch "sein Wesen treiben", "viel Wesens um eine Sache machen", "Gewese".

"Bauwesen" bezeichnt damit *alles, was im Bau getrieben wird*, *das Treiben um den Bau*, *den Baubetrieb*.

Ich kann für diese Deutung keine Quelle zitieren. Aber die Bedeutung dieser Worte ist meiner Meinung nach hier eindeutig. Denn die Wort "Bankwesen", "Bauwesen", "Rechnungswesen", "Verlagswesen", etc. werden nicht verwendet, um die Essenz der Bank, des Baus, des Rechnens, der Verlage, etc. zu bezeichnen, sondern um *den Betrieb*, der Bank, des Baus, der Rechnung, der Verlage (bei der Literatur würde man sagen: *das literarische Leben*) zu bezeichnen.